# Logical principles that entail each other

Tags: logic

I have read somewhere (I don't remember where, unfortunately) that two logical principles can be said to entail each other. Could someone help me making sense of this claim, which I find quite obscure? What would it take for two logical principles to entail each other? Could you also give a basic example please?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this sort of thing is meant?

Take intuitionist propositional logic -- i.e. [usually] your favourite classical logical minus the double negation rule. Now, with that as background, consider the following two logical principles:

1. The double negation rule DN: from $\neg\neg\alpha$ you can infer $\alpha$.
2. The law of excluded middle LEM: at any stage in a proof, you can infer $(\alpha \lor \neg\alpha)$.

Then it is easy to show that, against the given background, these two logical principles are equivalent in the following sense: anything you can prove using DN (plus the assumed background principles) can be proved using LEM (plus the assumed background principles), and vice versa.

(It would be careless to say that DN and LEM entail each other: they are rules rather than propositions. So it would be right to find the claim e.g. that DN and LEM entail each other obscure. It's rather that the two rules warrant the same entailment claims, given a certain background.)

This is typical. We can be working in some background system $S$, and find that -- against the assumed background -- adding the principle $P_1$ or the principle $P_2$ comes to just the same; anything provable using $S + P_1$ is provable using  $S + P_2$ and vice versa. It is then natural to say that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are equivalent, given $S$.